# "fish appear to be 30% smaller because of the curvature of the tunnel"

Tags: everyday-life, refraction, lenses

I recently visited an aquarium in Malaysia and there was a sign saying that the exhibits in their main tank appear to be smaller by 30% especially when viewed through their tunnel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiESyGtsUus; not my video).

I was wondering why would the fish appear to be smaller by 30% since water magnifies an object by 30%. Has this got to do with the curvature of the window, or the material (acrylic, by the way; refraction through three mediums)?

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Ask also if you'd like to know the math behind the "30% " decrease, then I can edit the answer to put it as a foot note.

Answer (score 2):

In the aquarium tunnel the fish appears smaller because the acrylic with the water behind it creates a *diverging* lens. You can see in the ray diagram below that fish inside the aquarium appears smaller(you outside will see a diminished or smaller virtual image). The sides of the tunnel taken approximately cylindrical( that is in the arc of a circle).

[image]

Using small angle approximations the size of the fish decreases by approximately 30%(factoring in refractive index of water and of acrylic where the refractive index of acrylic cancels out in the mathematics) if you calculate the angle of divergence. Thus the fish *do* appear smaller in such an arrangement for viewing in a tunnel.

Note: You can think of this scenario like the opposite of a fish bowl where fish look larger inside the bowl but here it's like *you* are inside the fish bowl and hence the outside world(fish in aquarium) looks smaller by the law of reversibility of light.